# Uncaught TypeError: Glide is not a constructor - Using Glide.js with Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix, laravel-8, glidejs

I have Glide.js installed on Laravel 8. I was using the CDN to test it out and everything was working fine. When I installed it with NPM, I get this:

Uncaught TypeError: Glide is not a constructor

This is how I have it in bootstrap.js:

`window.Glide = require('@glidejs/glide');`

The Javascript is complied fine into app.js. I just can't figure out why it's showing that error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide';
window.Glide = Glide;
```